# How do I run shell command in golang

Tags: bash, shell, go

I have a shell command

```
set -a  source /etc/environment; set +a
```

I want to run this command to refresh my env file

the code I tried to do

```
cmd, err := exec.Command("bash", "set -a  source /etc/environment; set +a").Output()
    fmt.Println("cmd=================>", cmd)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
```

it gave me exit status 127

Comment: Errors are normally written to stderr. Check stderr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
cmd, err := exec.Command("bash","-c", "set -a  source /etc/environment; set +a").Output()
    fmt.Println("cmd=================>", cmd)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
```